# passing parameter in report viewer by using visual studio 2010 - VB.net

Tags: reportviewer

I have been trying to get report in visual studio 2010 by passing parameters such as `startDate`, `endDate` and etc., but I haven't done it yet

Can someone help me to generate this report by using report viewer.

I prefer vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of making you scared, you can simply go through some tutorials and do some R & D so that you get some grasp on the topics. If it is just that you have started then go through [SSRS Series Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194097/SSRS-Series-Part-I-Various-ways-of-Report-creation) first. and then see the other links also

[Adding parameters to reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337401%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Format Date Time](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/05f16099-c8d7-46b1-b719-e47c57a2845b)

[SSRS Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522859%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[SSRS Series Part-1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194097/SSRS-Series-Part-I-Various-ways-of-Report-creation)

Hope this helps !